# How can I save the destination address of my transaction?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-gui, transaction-information

From [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/6puzvw/how_can_i_provably_save_the_destination_address/):

> I might be mistaken, but I read once that there is a flag that 'saves' the destination address of your transactions in your wallet file. I am not sure if it's the actual address that is saved or the one-time public key, but I'd like more information on that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the CLI the command is as follows:

`set store-tx-info <1|0>`

Where `1` as argument will store transaction info. Note that for newly created wallets it is automatically set to 1. Thus, newly created wallets will automatically save transaction info.

> I am not sure if it's the actual address that is saved or the one-time public key,

It will save the transaction hash, amount, private transaction key (you can obtain this by using `get_tx_key <transaction-hash>`), recipient's address, and payment ID.

---

Note that the GUI will automatically save transaction info as well. If you go to the `History` page and click on `Details` of a particular transaction, it will show all relevant information.